# Como pegar o id do link com jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tenho uma grid e na ultima coluna vou ter um link que vai ser seguinte formato:

id.1

id.2

id.3

id.4

Gostaria de ao clicar no link

```
<a id="id."'.$row["id"].' href="#">
```

O Jquery identificar o id para eu poder chamar uma funcionalidade. Como posso pegar o evento do clique no link?

Pegando da button é tranquilo

```
 $('#postar').click(function() {
```

Como poderia pegar o clique do link somente por um pedaço da "id"

```
$('#id').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar como o [ricardolobo sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166977/129), usando um seletor que procura elementos cuja ID começa por uma dada string. Um exemplo seria assim (jsFiddle):

```js
$('[id^="id."]').on('click', function(){
 var nr = this.id.slice(3);
 alert(nr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="id.1" href="#">Numero 1</a>
<a id="id.2" href="#">Numero 2</a>
<a id="id.3" href="#">Numero 3</a>
```

Outra alternativa seria usar a posição dos elementos, e ler o index, sem estar ligado à ID. Neste caso vale a pena referir que o index começa em `0`, por isso o primeiro elemento seria o numero `0`.

Seria algo assim:

```js
$('nav a').on('click', function() {
    var nr = $(this).index();
    alert(nr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <a id="id.1" href="#">Numero 1</a>
    <a id="id.2" href="#">Numero 2</a>
    <a id="id.3" href="#">Numero 3</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Neste caso para um **id** com o nome **id1**:

```
$('[id^=id1]')
```

Comment: Ricardo, meu id=1 ou id=2 ou id=3 como faria para pegar somente o numero depois do ID?

Comment: Ricardo, consegui assim: var id = $(this).attr('id');

Answer (score 0):

```
function listarAtivos(user) {

    let dados

    // faço o teste , comparando a lista de id que esta vindo com o que esta em acesso
    if (user.id != usuario.id) {
        // so vai imprimri caso não seja igual ao usuario logado


        dados = '<div class="card w-75">'
        dados += '<div class="card-body">'
        dados += '<input type="hidden" id="titulo_escondido" name="titulo_escondido" value=' + user.apelido + '>'
        dados += '<h5 class="card-title">' + user.apelido + '</h5>'
        dados += '<input type="hidden" id="codigo_escondido" name="codigo_escondido" value=' + user.id + '>'
        dados += '<p class="card-text">Deseja bater papo com você.</p>'
        dados += '<button type="button" id="aceitar_chat" value=' + user.id + ' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_chat">Vamos ?</button>'
        dados += '</div>'
        dados += '</div>'

        // coloca as informações na div
        $('#div_central').append(dados)

    }
}
```

Para esse caso eu usei assim . Criei um card e nele tem o botão que chama meu modal , dai eu coloquei o valor nesse botão ai eu pego o click

```
 $('body').on('click', '#aceitar_chat', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
                // esse id e capturado com base no valer que eu passo no botao
            let id = $(this).val()


        })
```